# Jquery :Automatically change the width equal to an element

Tags: jquery, html, css

First, sorry for my english is bad :)

`dm3` a width depends on the `tx1...n`, `tx1...n` automatically sorted 2-3-4 -... column width when the window is changed, or a different module appear changed `dm3` width.

Now I want a simple jquery, when `dm3` change the width, `dm1` will automatically change the width equal to `dm3`.

Note: `dm1` changes when `dm3` change, not just change when the page loads.

EX:

```
<div class="dm1">
<div class="to1">...</div>
<div class="to2">...</div>
</div>
<div class="dm2">
....
</div>
<div class="dm3">
<div class="tx1">..Content..</div>
<div class="tx2">..Content..</div>
<div class="tx3">..Content..</div>
...
<div class="txn">..Content..</div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<div class="dm1" style="width: 500px/600px;">
<div class="to1">...</div>
<div class="to2">...</div>
</div>
<div class="dm2">
....
</div>
<div class="dm3"> /* div width is 500px/600px */
<div class="tx1">..Content..</div>
<div class="tx2">..Content..</div>
<div class="tx3">..Content..</div>
...
<div class="txn">..Content..</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work for you:

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/veusr0xn/1/)

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() { // On load or window resize
    var dm3Width = $('.dm3').width() // Get dm3 width
    $('.dm1').width(dm3Width); // Make dm1 width match dm3 width
});
```