# Jquery launch as soon as the page loads

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() { 
  var dm3Width = $('.dm3').width() 
  $('.dm1').width(dm3Width); 
});
```

Demo Here: https://jsfiddle.net/veusr0xn/

It changes `dm1`, based on the width of `dm3`. But it runs only after I adjusted the size of the window. How does it run as soon as the page loads?

Thank so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your query under `$( document ).ready(function()` Scope so when document will load your query will automatically work

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
     var width=$(".dm3").width();
     $(".dm1").css('width',width);
     $(window).resize(function() {
       var dm3 = $('.dm3').width();
       $(".dm1").css('width',dm3);
     });
  });
```

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
    var width=$(".dm3").width();
    $(".dm1").css('width',width);

});

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: resolved ?
$( document ).ready(function() { 
var width=$(".dm3").width(); 
$(".dm1").css('width',width);
 $(window).resize(function() {
   var dm3 = $('.dm3').width();
    $(".dm1").css('width',dm3);
    });
});

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for a script to deal with dimensions. CSS is mature enough to deal with practically every presentation aspects and a width is a rather basic rule to set.

Instead of dealing with it in Javascript (very inefficient), I recommend you to put both divs inside a container and set its width to 200px, then add @media rule to it. You will have exactly the same flexibility but won't be at the mercy of scripted looks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dm">
  <div class="dm3">
    DM3
  </div>

  <div class="dm1">
    DM1
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dm { width: 200px; }
.dm3 { background-color: blue; }
.dm1 { background-color: breen; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .dm {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

See it in action with this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a1fyrf6x/1/).

Comment: My demo is a simple example. Width of dm3 dependent child element. So width of dm3 is not fixed.

Comment: @LêTùng I just noticed that and fixed by adding the `@media` rule to `.dm` :) check updated Fiddle. You will be thankful some day if you get rid of javscript hacks for presentation.

Comment: The point is, if widths are dependant, tell css that it is. Not javascript.

Comment: This is my previous posts :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430088/jquery-automatically-change-the-width-equal-to-an-element.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
$(window).on('resize',function() {
    var dm3Width = $('.dm3').width() // Get dm3 width
    $('.dm1').width(dm3Width); // Make dm1 width match dm3 width
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

```css
.dm3 {
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.dm1 {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .dm3 {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dm3">
  DM3
</div>


<div class="dm1">
  DM1
</div>
```